# Использование mosquitto auth plugin в docker

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker-compose, mqtt

Создаю с помощью docker compose мини сервер с базой данных postgres и mosquitto mqtt.
Появилась необходимость использовать mosquitto auth plugin.
Хочу чтобы авторизация происходила с помощью таблицы из базы данных postgres.
В интернете видел инструкции по использованию  mosquitto auth plugin c postgres.
Но я никак не могу найти инструкцию, как добавить к mosquitto auth plugin.

Ниже мой docker compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:14.8-alpine3.18
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "max_connections=50"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=1GB"
      - "-c"
      - "effective_cache_size=4GB"
      - "-c"
      - "work_mem=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "maintenance_work_mem=512MB"
      - "-c"
      - "random_page_cost=1.1"
      - "-c"
      - "temp_file_limit=10GB"
      - "-c"
      - "log_min_duration_statement=200ms"
      - "-c"
      - "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=10s"
      - "-c"
      - "lock_timeout=1s"
      - "-c"
      - "statement_timeout=60s"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.max=10000"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.track=all"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mosquitto/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.2
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PG_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PG_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - postgres

  mqtt-broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    user: mosquitto
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./mosquitto/config/password.txt:/mosquitto/password.txt
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - data:/mosquitto/data
    ports:
      - target: 1883
        published: 1883
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.10

  mqtt-pub:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    command: sh -c "mosquitto_pub -h mqtt-broker -t test -m 'Hello World' -u Frog -P 1234"
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-broker
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.11

  mqtt-sub:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    command: sh -c "mosquitto_sub -h mqtt-broker -t test -u Frog -P 1234"
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-broker
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.12

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  data:
    name: "mqtt-broker-data"

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

  mqtt-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.10.0/24

  postgres-data:
```

Напишите, как добавить к mosquitto auth плагин, который будет работать на основе контейнера с postgres. Я пробовал просто добавить файл к volumes, однако там нужно билдить его с помощью make. При этом нужно указывать путь к mosquitto, а я не понимаю, где он находится в контейнере mqtt-broker